# $ in $.ajax not defined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery to connect HTML and Python, but the following code won't work because $ is not defined. I researched it and found nothing that could help me that I haven't already done.

```
<script
          src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"
          integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
          crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    
    function myFunction() {
    const firstname = document.getElementById('fname').value;
    const lastname = document.getElementById('lname').value;

    const dict_values = {firstname, lastname}
    const s = JSON.stringify(dict_values);
    console.log(s)
    window.alert(s)
    $.ajax({
        url:"/test",
        type:"POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(s)});
}
  
</script>
```

I added more to the first script, but nothing changed.

Comment: Turn it into a runnable snippet, I tried your code and it seems to work fine. So unless there's more context we can't find out the problem with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrity value of your jquery is incorrect, this can be seen in your browser console with an error message looks like this:

> Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8='. The resource has been blocked.

You can change it to the following instead: `integrity="sha256-oP6HI9z1XaZNBrJURtCoUT5SUnxFr8s3BzRl+cbzUq8="`

Comment: That did not seem to work. Here is the error message: {"firstname":"asd","lastname":"sdf"}
?username=asd&user-password=asd:32  Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Hi @Burrito, are you sure you modified your `script` tag to use the new `integrity` value? As long as the ordering is correct (Jquery script is loaded before `myFunction`, it should work fine)

Comment: Sorry, it seemed to have just fixed it self. I refreshed and it just got rid of the error. Thanks for the help!